# Can we use varnish with mariadb/mysql backends directly?

Tags: mysql, varnish, mariadb

I was wondering if Varnish could front end a backend pool of mariadb/mysql servers. 
If Varnish can front end only HTTP servers, then I guess the attempt to front end database servers such as mariadb/mysql would be futile. Perhaps only load balancing with HAproxy (and not caching) can be achieved for a database back end pool. Please confirm.

Comment: What would you achieve if you were able to "front end" databases with this caching solution?

Comment: We could load balance, cache (to get improved performance) and live with a single virtual IP for sql clients to access DB. We can get high availability and load balancing while sql clients live with one IP address access of database server. (Especially when the data is mainly read only from DB)

Comment: MySQL is quicker than any caching solution for serving cached version of its data. Using InnoDB or TokuDB with **proper** server configuration outperforms anything on the market, from memcached, redis, varnish or whatever. It also handles connections great. Same applies for MariaDB / Percona. If you were to cache SQL result into varnish, you'd just duplicate your data, waste storage and make stuff slower. Load balancing can be done on app level, and there are many ways of load balancing - varnish isn't something for that. Basically, doing nothing > varnish, in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to understanding wrong about "frontend". Frontend on website application relates to static files such as javascript, images, css ... files.
Caching for Mysql should be in another way like query caching, result caching...etc